# should table relationships be used if not required

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

i'm working with an existing client-side legacy database that we're converting to MySQL for online use.

it's effectively one giant table, and no relationships exist.

for each record, there are several contact points - first name, last name, title, street, city, state, zip, etc., repeated for several entities.  my initial thought was to separate each of these entities into it's own table with the above mentioned columns, and use FKs to link them up with traditional joins, etc.

but, after going through the entire dataset and talking with the original author, it turns out that none of these contact points will ever repeat (each will be unique to each record), nor is any other information related to these contact points.

so - AFAICT - there's no real 'use' for relationship tables, except possibly semantics or transparency.  the dataset isn't huge but it's not small either (between 50,000 and 100,000 records), so i wonder if if fact it might be more efficient to just keep the single-table structure intact and skip joins altogether.

is there any reason to use separate tables in a situation like this?

tyia

Comment: AFAIK, For columns like, title, street , city etc, putting it into separate table shall only improve performance if the frequency of data change is huge, otherwise it wont make any difference.

Comment: +1 I just asked a variation of this question moments ago. Hope to see a good answer!

Comment: @Madmartigan - what did you end up doing?  single table or relationships?

Comment: It's actually not quite the same question, and it is still [open](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5810761/consolidating-tables-with-one-to-one-relationships). I've received a wide variety of answers so I'm not sure what to do yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mainframes have used flat file formats for decades quite effectively so I think you can certainly get away with leaving the table as is. That being said, I would consider the following questions:

- Are there many queries that use the '*' operator retrieving all columns from the database or are the queries mature enough to not include those columns that are not required. If the former is the case you may want to move them to a separate table for performance reasons
- Will there ever be a requirement in the future where multiple 'contact' entries for a record WILL be required. You might save a few headaches by doing the conversion now vs. later

I suspect it's just one big flat file and probably will fit as is with no real need to normalize. If you would wind up with a 1 to 1 relationship to the other table and you aren't pulling all columns with every query, flatfile wins.

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely, even if only for preventing *technical debt*.

Huge tables are always more expensive to maintain -- they have a higher learning curve (so they cost more to train a new developer) and they are not as easy to read "instantly" (meaning that it costs more to even look at the table).

It should be a goal to make code as immediately apparent as possible. A "USER_DATA" table which includes the contact info is about as intuitive as possible. That pattern exists everywhere and everyone has seen it. It requires and invites almost no thought because it is so obvious.

The pattern you're describing above makes an experienced developer pause and wonder why it was done that way. That developer might then seek out the original author so that he can understand why it was done that way and not the more intuitive way...

Comment: i think you're right, and i'll use the more natural multiple table structure.  and you're right - it did make me wonder, and i did contact the original author - the answer was basically 'inexperience' - the original was designed in the 90s.  i gave pepto the accept since his response was a little before yours, but i think both your answers were good - +1 for your time.  thx

Answer (score 0):

In this case it may not be much useful, but keeping so many columns in a single table where we have large number of records is not suggested. Better to split the table and store the basic columns in one table like name, password etc, and other descriptive information in another table.

Answer (score 0):

There is no benefit to splitting out first name, last name, title, street, city, state, zip.
The only good reason so to do would be to add value to each of those fields, for example you could define 'city' in terms of 'state' because they have a relationship but then you would need an ID column to disambiguate 'Springfield, Ill' form 'Springfield, Mass' and queries would get more complicated and performance would be marginally worse. So leaving it all in one table in a 'de-normalised' form in this instance seems like good sense to me.